# Style embedded ControlTemplate using Style

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, infragistics, wpf-style

Im using Infragistics controls with Theming. The Template property is set on a Trigger.

That Template is configured further up the hierarchy so I cannot edit directly but I want to change one of the properties set.

e.g.

Template set on a trigger (truncated)

```
<Style x:Key="FxtPaneTabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type igDock:PaneTabItem}">
  <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis" />
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="igDock:XamDockManager.PaneLocation" Value="Unpinned">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static igDock:PaneTabItem.DockableTabItemTemplateKey}}" />
      </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The template configured in unreachable code (truncated)

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static igDock:PaneTabItem.DockableTabItemTemplateKey}" TargetType="{x:Type igDock:PaneTabItem}">
 <Border x:Name="ctrlBorder" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" MinHeight="25">
  <controls:CardPanel>
  <controls:CardPanel x:Name="Background">
   <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="25">
    <Border x:Name="Border" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
    <Border x:Name="HighlightBorder" Margin="0" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static igDock:DockManagerBrushKeys.TabbedListNotActiveInnerBorderFillKey}}" BorderThickness="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
   </Grid>
  </controls:CardPanel>
 </Border>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

I only want to override the Border (x:Name="ctrlBorder") MinHeight property. Is this possible without replicating the entire ControlTemplate in my code base. and changing this single property?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, you can't change the template, but you can create a custom behavior (or add code as on the code behind) on the code that you used that control.

On that code, go over the control visual hierarchy and find the border by name. than you can change its properties.

It's important that you will try to find the elements (border on your case) on the visual tree **after** the **Loaded** event has accor on that object, because you need that the visual will be created already

**Finding visual elements on the visual hierarchy:**

```
        public static List<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj, bool searchWithinAFoundT = true) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            List<T> list = new List<T>();
            if (depObj != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
                {
                    DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                    if (child != null && child is T)
                    {
                        list.Add((T)child);

                        // this means that an element is not expected to contain elements of his type
                        if (!searchWithinAFoundT) { continue; }
                    }

                    List<T> childItems = FindVisualChildren<T>(child, searchWithinAFoundT);
                    if (childItems != null && childItems.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in childItems)
                        {
                            list.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
```

It's a little dirty but it can help on a specific cases